# Zend Framework 2 set body

Tags: zend-framework2

Is there a way to just set the body in Zend Framework 2? In Zend Framework 1 I could do it this way

```
$this->getResponse()->setBody('Hello World')
```

I found a way to set content in Zend Framework 2 but this also overwrites the layout and that's not what I want.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I finally got the solution. To change the content in the layout, just type in controller's action

```
$this->layout()->content = 'foobar';
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do that....

## ModuleName/src/ModuleName/Controller/IndexController.php

```
<?PHP
namespace ModuleName\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

class IndexController extends AbstractActionController
{
    protected $helloWorldTable;

    public function indexAction()
    {
        return new ViewModel(array(
            'foo' => 'Hello World From Zend Framework 2!',
        ));
    }
}
```

## ModuleName/view/ModuleName/index/index.phtml

```
<?PHP
$this->headTitle('Some Site...');
echo "$hello";
?>
```

## Application/view/layout/layout.phtml

doctype(); ?>

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <?php echo $this->headMeta()->appendName('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0') ?>

        <!-- Le styles -->
        <?php echo $this->headLink(array('rel' => 'shortcut icon', 'type' => 'image/vnd.microsoft.icon', 'href' => $this->basePath() . '/images/favicon.ico')) ?>

        <!-- Scripts -->
        <?php echo $this->headScript()->prependFile($this->basePath() . '/js/html5.js', 'text/javascript', array('conditional' => 'lt IE 9',))
                                      ->prependFile($this->basePath() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js')
                                      ->prependFile($this->basePath() . '/js/jquery.min.js') ?>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                <div class="container">
                    <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </a>
                    <a class="brand" href="<?php echo $this->url('index') ?>"><?php echo $this->translate('Spamus') ?></a>
                    <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                        <ul class="nav">
                            <li class="active"><a href="<?php echo $this->url('index') ?>"><?php echo $this->translate('Home') ?></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <?php echo $this->content; ?>
            <hr>
            <footer>
                <p>&copy; 2012 - 2013 by YourSite <?php echo $this->translate('All rights reserved.') ?></p>
            </footer>
        </div> <!-- /container -->
        <?php echo $this->inlineScript() ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Whatever you changed Response body in controller, when zf2 MvcEvent::EVENT_RENDER trigger, a new Response body will be rebuilt. So correct way is change Response body **AFTER** MvcEvent::EVENT_RENDER.

Add this to your controller:

```
 $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Application')->getEventManager()->attach(\Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent::EVENT_RENDER, function($event){
     $event->getResponse()->setContent('foobar');
 }, -10000);
```

Comment: When I add this to my controller, I get an empty page with 'foobar'. That's what I didn't wanted. I just want to set the Body, so that the rest of the layout is still there. In other words: I want to set the content (echo $this->content; in layout.phtml) of my layout file.